# Wrong coordinates in layout

Tags: qgis, coordinate-system, print-composer, epsg

My map is not exporting the right coordinates.

As you can see it makes a local sistem.
It should be around 46 N , 20 E.

[image]

[image]

[image]

Do you have any idea what am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 5):

If you wish to show your grid in degrees you need to change the **grids CRS** to EPSG:4326 (WGS84), see:

[image]

Choose a suiting interval as well as your desired coordinate format.

[image]

Comment: it s not working for me, simply I tried all the options, using other map and no result. The is not creating coordinates, but creating the right ones, because they are shown in local coordinate system with no reference

Comment: thank you!! basically the main problem was with the interval :)