# QGIS Change Grid labels and scale

Tags: qgis, coordinate-system, labeling, grids-graticules, utm

I create a map in QGIS, in which I added Grids with labels and Scale.

So in the map the scale is not equal to interline grids.

I know it is related to projection system and location. but how do I fix it in QGIS.

[image]

last I want to show labels of grids in Degrees not UTM. how?

Comment: Check out https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/381195/107424