# QGIS Lost my layer settings

Tags: qgis, coordinate-system, layers, export

I am new user of QGIS and I am facing this problem

I created a map in my main project and so some layers. it was working pretty good.

But I don't know what I'd changed in parameters. and it gave me a blank map or dark.

[image]

so my projection configuration is:

[image]

and the layer is

[image]

its grid projection is
[image]

Comment: What is the source layer? Looks like a WMS layer? Or some other online source? How did you add it into QGIS?

Comment: I created them from other program and some I downloaded from Sentinel-2.

Comment: Post a screenshot of your actual project with the layers panel, not just the print composer. Some web layers don't like to be re-projected. For WGS:84 you should use EPSG:4326 and for web Mercator EPSG:3857.

Comment: this was my project and works very good
https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/385903/qgis-change-grid-labels-and-scale

Answer (score 1):

I solved this problem:
1st Set main project projection to (WGS 84 EPSG:3395)
2nd all images to (EPSG:4326 WGS 84)
3rd in layout manager I use (use project CRS)
and Finally I rest the Extents parameters to my AOI
and everything back to normal

Many thanks you all